# PromptTemplate, second iteration not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, langchain

I am trying to make a bot with history and a custom prompt:

The issue is that when I call it the first time it works. When I do again it stops working. If I remove the template it works

```js
const noInputPrompt = new PromptTemplate({
  inputVariables: [],
  template: "You are an assistant of a doctor and help customer on that." +
    "You do a flow, collect name, last name and email. Then finish the call. Do that one by one. So you say hello and then ask first question.",
});

const chain = new ConversationChain({ llm: chatModel, memory: memory, prompt: noInputPrompt });

const stream = await chain.call({
  input: input,
  // Add your callbacks here
});
```